# Why are my objects rotating with my camera?

Tags: opengl, opentk

I am working with [this](https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp) C# library that wraps OpenGL. I am trying to understand why my objects in the scene are rotating as I yaw my camera (view matrix).

Here is an image where I have 4 separate cubes in a row with no spacing.

[image: Not Rotated]

If I yaw my camera you can see that the cubes have also rotated. Notice the red arrows which point to the side of a cube that is now visible:

[image: After Rotation]

I was expecting that these cubes would not rotate. It looked to me as if something in my code is wrong for their model matrix, but I'm not sure I understand what is happening.

Every render frame I am doing this for each cube:

```
shader["model_matrix"].SetValue(ModelMatrix);
```

`ModelMatrix` is calculated as follows, once:

```
this.ModelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(worldX * size, worldY * size, worldZ * size));
```

`world` variables are offsets for the position of the cube, and size is just the length. Each render frame my view matrix is being set:

```
shader["view_matrix"].SetValue(camera.ViewMatrix);
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;

attribute vec3 in_position;
attribute vec3 in_normal;

varying vec3 vertex_light_position;
varying vec3 vertex_normal;

void main(void)
{
  vertex_normal = in_normal;
  vertex_light_position = normalize(vec3(1, 1, 0));
  gl_Position = projection_matrix * model_matrix * view_matrix * vec4(in_position, 1);
}
```

I have been basing this extended example off of the tutorial [here](https://github.com/giawa/opengl4tutorials/tree/master/OpenGLTutorial15). I am probably missing something basic (I am just starting OpenGL), so thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Usually the order of multiplication should be projection * (view * (model * (vertex position)))), since matrix multiplication is not commutative in general. You have the model & view matrices flipped in your vertex shader.

Comment: @DMGregory Reading those parenthesis agitates me... I suppose it is a good way to visualize OpenGL's use of ***post-multiplication***, but for some reason seeing that series of transforms written that way bugs me more than it probably should ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As DMGregory commented, your model_matrix and view_matrix are in wrong order in your shader code. If you look at the [tutorial's shader code](https://github.com/giawa/opengl4tutorials/blob/master/OpenGLTutorial15/OpenGLTutorial15/Program.cs#L344), you'll see your mistake.

I really liked [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) about matrices. It simply explains how the order of transformations and rotations should be. There is also couple great general explanations about how graphics pipeline works in [computerphile's channel on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzH6n4zXuckrPkEUK5iMQrQyvj9Z6WCrm), including information about matrices.

[image: MVP matrix order]
[image: MVP steps illustrated]

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks for the visuals and link. It is making more sense now. =)